# Embedding a UIViewController with dynamic height inside parent view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am displaying a UIViewController(In NotificationContentExtension) with a child view controller. The parent controller is just adding to its view the view of child controller as subview.

The subview is all built with autolayout and constraints, which renders fine when not embedded in a view controller.

Currently, the parent notification is displayed as big as the parent view controller's view is configured to be in the extension's Info.plist file.

If I provide a height to the childcontroller's view in the parent view it renders as big as the parent but in case I don't initialise its frame, it doesn't render the child controller's view elements.

What I am seeking is to open the controller as big as the child view container's dynamic height make it to be.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, I believe what you're trying to achieve is a Modal "popup" View Controller than is smaller (in some way) than the View Controller that calls it, similar to the functionality of an Alert View Controller...

Go to your Storyboard and click on the child view controller with the custom height, then open the right pane to view the Size Inspector. I'm assuming here your Simulated Size = "Freeform" with your height and width. This will allow you to actually resize the View Controller in the Storyboard but the view controller will show up fullscreen.

Now click on the Attributes Inspector and in the 4th grouping down, check the box for Content Size "Use Preferred Explicit Size" and type in your simulated size. This will allow your Modal view controller to show up at the exact size you're asking.

To do this programmatically, try this in the calling ViewController's prepare for segue implementation:

destinationVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 400.0)

Cheers :)

Comment: Hey actually we are shipping this as part of the SDK, so we don't have any storyboards, rather the entire UI is being done programmatically. Can you suggest how can I achieve the same in code.

Comment: I edited my answer above. See if this works for you :)